# Как запретить перенос элементов, содержащих блочные элементы?

Tags: html, css

К примеру, такой код:

```
<style>
    .a {
        white-space:nowrap;
        width: 50px;
    }
    .b {
        display: inline;
    }
</style>
<div class="a">
    <div class="b">Инлайн
        <div class="c">Блочный</div>
    </div>
    <div class="b">Инлайн</div>
    <div class="b">Инлайн</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Олега, Чтобы отформатировать код, выделите его мышью и нажмите на кнопку 101010 редактора.

Comment: Так и сделал)))

Comment: Вы забыли поставить перенос строки перед кодом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно для блочных элементов применить float: left;

nowrap здесь не прокатит

Comment: Вам спасибо, но в моем частном случае и этот способ не подходит.
Проблему решил с помощью table

Answer (score 0):

Если я правильно понял, то тебе нужно, чтобы весь твой код высветился в одну строку?

```
.c {
    display: inline - block;
}
```

Но я не понял, где именно это надо - контекст.

Answer (score 0):

Мне это помогло   text-transform: none;